# Complicated PHP Error : Trying to escape an array

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli, escaping

I'm trying to mysqli escape an array mysqli_real_escape_string function.
But it won't work because it expects a string.
So I use this :

```
$items = array_map('mysqli_real_escape_string', $link, $_POST['items']);
```

where $link is my database connection and $_POST['items'] is the array.
But I get this error :

```
Warning: array_map(): Argument #2 should be an array
```

So I changed it to :

```
$items = array_map('mysqli_real_escape_string', $_POST['items']);
```

where the 2nd argument is an array and then I get this message :

```
Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given
```

So I changed it again to :

```
$items = array_map('mysqli_real_escape_string', $_POST['items'], $link);
```

but now I got this :

```
Warning: array_map(): Argument #3 should be an array
```

After some research, I tried this codes :

```
$items = array_map('mysqli_real_escape_string', $_POST['items'] [,$link]);
$items = array_map('mysqli_real_escape_string($link)', $_POST['items']);
```

but none of the worked.

Any help is appriciated.
Thanks.

EDIT :
I've tried this :

```
function escape_array($array){
    global $link;
    mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $array);
    return;
}

$items = array_map('escape_array', $_POST['items']);
echo $items;
```

which should call the mysqli_real_escape_string with the connection but I get this error instead :

```
( ! ) Notice: Array to string conversion in D:\wamp64\www\sellerpanel\test.php on line 21
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0007  370968  {main}( )   ...\test.php:0
Array
```

Comment: You could write your own function that calls `mysqli_real_escape_string` with the connection. I'd use parameterized queries though.

Comment: @user3783243 I had made changes with your suggestion. Mind checking it out?

Comment: Use prepared and parameterized queries and you won't have to mess around with escaping data before queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with an anonymous function that imports the `$link` variable.

```
$items = array_map(function($x) use ($link) {
    return mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $x);
}, $_POST['items']);
```

However, you really shouldn't be using `mysqli_real_escape_string` in the first place. Use a prepared statement and `mysqli_stmt_bind_param()`.

Comment: I had coped the code you provided with no modifications (Since I belive there is nothing to modify) but I still get the error : Notice: Array to string conversionin D:\wamp64\www\sellerpanel\test.php on line 18
Call Stack
# Time Memory Function Location
1 0.0007 371192 {main}( ) ...\test.php:0
Array

Comment: What is line 18?

Comment: That error is probably coming from the code that uses `$items`, not this assignment.

Comment: The code that uses $items is 'echo'. Full code :
<?php

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
 
 require 'system/config.php';

 $items = array_map(function($x) use ($link) {
     return mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $x);
 }, $_POST['items']);

 echo $items;

}

?>. The error now apperas on line 19 which is 'echo $items;'

Comment: You can't echo an array. Use `var_dump($items);`